# How to get percent of drill through page (with the filter) and total (not affected by that filter) in drill though page?

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I have a project that have to analyze time spend for all projects in the company.
The main page have all the project and detail and each project have a drill though to that project page which have ppl spending time for that project. And I want to to calculate the percent hours spend for that project compare to all project in that page. How could I do it?

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution. I can create a new table from the main table by this function.

```
SUMMARIZE( <table>, <groupBy_columnName>[, <groupBy_columnName>]…[, <name>, <expression>]…)
```

Then use the sum all hours of the project in project page / sum hours of all project to get the percentage time of the project in total.